# laravel で Undefined variable エラー

Tags: php, laravel

laravelで下記のようにコードを書きました。

```
$array = array('hoge','fuga');

$grid->filter(function($filter){
   $filter->equal('column', 'column_label')->select($array);
});
```

ただ、この場合だと「Undefined variable: array」としてエラーが表示されます。
以下のような記述であれば正常に動作するのですが、前述のコードで動作させるにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？

```
$grid->filter(function($filter){
   $array = array('hoge','fuga');
   $filter->equal('column', 'column_label')->select($array);
});
```

自分なりに調べて

```
global $array;
```

なども追加してみたのですが、上手く行きませんでした。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`use` を使います。

```
$array = ['hoge','fuga'];

$grid->filter(function ($filter) use ($array) {
   $filter->equal('column', 'column_label')->select($array);
});
```

クロージャのスコープについて詳しくは[PHPのドキュメント参照](http://php.net/manual/ja/functions.anonymous.php)。